# How to use/enable EventHubsEventSource traces for EventHubClient

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to enable EventHubsEventSource traces in **azure-event-hubs-dotnet/src/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/EventHubClient.cs** for example trace them events in a file.
Can someone please tell me how to enable these kind of events ?
I have tried using a custom **EventTraceListener** but the class **EventHubsEventSource** is marked as internal so not visible from my listener.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The event source implementation is internal, but is available to listeners by opting into the source by name.  In the [`OnEventSourceCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.oneventsourcecreated?view=netcore-3.1) of your listener, you should be able to filter by the name of the event source.

That would look something like:

```cs
protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
{
    base.OnEventSourceCreated(eventSource);

    if (eventSource.Name == "Microsoft-Azure-EventHubs")
    {
        EnableEvents(eventSource, EventLevel.Verbose);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** *The following is based on a misreading of the question and applies to the current generation of the Event Hubs client library, `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`.  These statements do not hold true for the legacy client library, `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` which was subject of the question.  I'm going to leave this in tact for now, as it may be of interest to some readers.*

The event source implementation is internal, but is available to listeners by opting into sources with the `AzureEventSource` trait.

The easiest way to do so is to make use of the `AzureEventSourceListener`in the `Azure.Core` library. This [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#logging) demonstrates some approaches for using it.  Alternatively, the [`OnEventSourceCreated`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/core/Azure.Core/src/Diagnostics/AzureEventSourceListener.cs#L52) method in its source illustrates how you could integrate the trait into your own listener.

Comment: Hello Jesse,
Thanks for answer , if I understand correctly the AzureEventSourceListener is enabling the EventSource having the trait AzureEventSource. 
Correct me If I'm wrong but I don't see the definition of the trait on the EventHubsEventSource , did I miss something ?

Comment: You're correct.   All of the event sources in the Azure client libraries use that trait to make it easier to filter for them.   The trait being applied is a bit subtle, as it is aliased as a constant on the Core library and passed via constructor.   You can see it here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Diagnostics/EventHubsEventSource.cs#L52

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, you are pointing the **EventHubsEventSource** that is located **Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Diagnostics** namespace , when I look in the code of **[EventHubClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/src/EventHubClient.cs)** he is using the **EventHubsEventSource** which is located in the **Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs** namespace seems, that's not the same EventHubsEventSource  and on which we do not have the corresponding trait , Am I  wrong ? possible mismatch ?

Comment: Ah, apologies; the error is on my part.  Your question clearly stated that you were using the legacy SDK and I misread.  My statements are in reference to the current generation of the Event Hubs library and don't apply to Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.

Comment: I've updated to address the actual question that you were asking.   Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hello Jesse, thanks for answer no need to be sorry , works much better ;) . If I understand correctly the **Azure.Messaging.EventHubs** is the new generation of eventhubs library is there any steps migrating for the legacy to the new libraries or the package update and the code adaptation should be sufficient ?

Comment: Glad that we finally got you unblocked.  There are some API differences between the generations of the library, so upgrading is a breaking change.  There is a migration guide available here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/MigrationGuide.md. 
 We'd definitely advise doing so, if possible, as `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` is under active development and will be the version receiving new features going forward.   That said, the legacy SDK will continue to be supported for the foreseeable future and receive fixes and critical updates.